# magnific-popup loading icon while loading iframe

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I am using [magnific-popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) for loading external iFrame, which sometime takes some time in loading, While waiting, it shows blank screen.

Is there a way, I can show [COG type of icon](http://loadergenerator.com/) while waiting in loading.

[Reference](http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/zjtbr)

[Magnific-popup examples](http://codepen.io/collection/nLcqo/)

Answer (score 3):

Following works fine for me.

//JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.popiframe').magnificPopup({
       type:'iframe',
       iframe: {
            markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler your-special-css-class">'+
                        '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                        '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>            </iframe>'+
                    '</div>'
       }

    }); 
});
```

//CSS

```
.mfp-iframe-scaler iframe {
    background: url('/images/v2/loading.gif') no-repeat scroll center center #000000 !important;
}
```